# Cannot install Jupyter in windows 10

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have python 3.8.5 and pip 20.3.3 already installed in my pc.

I run the following command:

```
 pip install jupyterlab
```

I try to install Jupyter I get bellow error:

```
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Or something else that have a custom SSL certificate

Comment: I disconnected the vpn and tried it also not working

Comment: I am not behind a proxy